# OCTC compared to Miller's theorem

Tags: gain

I found -3dB frequency \$f_H\$ of the following circuit using both OCTC and Miller's theorem:

OCTC:

\$f_H=1/(2\pi [C_{gs}R_{sig}+C_{gd}(R_L(1+g_mR_L)+R_{sig})+C_LR_L])=652KHz\$

Miller's theorem:

\$f_{Hin}=1/(2\pi [C_{gs}R_{sig}+C_{gd}R_{sig}(1+g_mR_L)]=788KHz\$

\$f_{Hout}=1/(2\pi R_L(C_L+C_{gd}(1-1/k)))=3.79MHz\$

Hence,

\$f_H=1/\sqrt{1/f_{Hin}^2+1/f_{Hout}^2}=777KHz\$

I was then asked to shortly explain the discrepancies between the two results in view of the fact that OCTC and Miller's theorem give almost the same results in terms of time constants. Why is there over a 100KHz difference in this case?
[image]

Comment: I have shown my work; is there anyone here who could please try and explain the reason for the discrepancy between the OCTC and Miller's theorem in this case?

Comment: Why did you omit CL and RL in your secend solution?

Comment: @G36 Just corrected that. Still a large difference between OCTC and Miller -- why?

Comment: I have found these slides online that may answer your question (in particular slide 13): https://web.sonoma.edu/esee/courses/es330/units/OCTC_analysis.pdf

Comment: @FlyerDragon I'm trying to make sense of everything that's written there. Usually, my question states, these two methods yield nearly similar results. Yet here there's obviously a big difference. Is it simply because Miller overestimates the Cgd,input term and it underestimates the capacitor Cgd,output, as the slide reads?

Comment: @G36 So how does one account for this substantial difference between the two methods?

Comment: @G36 I now realize that the discrepancy is merely due to the fact that we were specifically asked to use the square root formula when using Miller's theorem, instead of just summing the time constants, or their inverse rather. The square root formula doesn't yield accurate results here as there is a dominant pole. Does this explanation make sense? Is it correct?

Comment: Is there anyone willing to please relate to my last comment?